# CSS - Text-overflow not working on large text

Tags: html, css

So I have this: http://jsfiddle.net/yw9Dg/

```
    <style>

.texto {
width:400px;
position:relative;
height:100%;
overflow: hidden !important;
text-overflow: ellipsis !important;
-o-text-overflow: ellipsis !important;
white-space: nowrap !important;
display:block !important;
}
</style>

<div class="texto">
wsdasdasdas asda sd as asdasda asdasd asda sdasdasd asdasdasd asd asdaswsdasdasdas asda sd as asdasda asdasd asda sdasdasd asdasdasd asd asdaswsdasdasdas asda sd as asdasda asdasd asda sdasdasd asdasdasd asd asdaswsdasdasdas asda sd as asdasda asdasd asda sdasdasd asdasdasd asd asdaswsdasdasdas asda sd as asdasda asdasd asda sdasdasd asdasdasd asd asdaswsdasdasdas asda sd as asdasda asdasd asda sdasdasd asdasdasd asd asdaswsdasdasdas asda sd as asdasda asdasd asda sdasdasd asdasdasd asd asdaswsdasdasdas asda sd as asdasda asdasd asda sdasdasd asdasdasd asd asdaswsdasdasdas asda sd as asdasda asdasd asda sdasdasd asdasdasd asd asdaswsdasdasdas asda sd as asdasda asdasd asda sdasdasd asdasdasd asd asdaswsdasdasdas asda sd as asdasda asdasd asda sdasdasd asdasdasd asd asdaswsdasdasdas asda sd as asdasda asdasd asda sdasdasd asdasdasd asd asdaswsdasdasdas asda sd as asdasda asdasd asda sdasdasd asdasdasd asd asdaswsdasdasdas asda sd as asdasda asdasd asda sdasdasd asdasdasd asd asdaswsdasdasdas asda sd as asdasda asdasd asda sdasdasd asdasdasd asd asdaswsdasdasdas asda sd as asdasda asdasd asda sdasdasd asdasdasd asd asdaswsdasdasdas asda sd as asdasda asdasd asda sdasdasd asdasdasd asd asdas</div>
```

It's a large text, but the text-overflow is only working with the first line, and what I need is to make it add the "..." at the end of the text. I can't find anything on Google helping to find a work around to this problem, what am I missing there?

Comment: Umm...The fiddle you posted is working for me. What browser are you using?

Comment: Google Chrome. Is that the problem?

Comment: Just tested on Opera and Firefox, and got the same result:

wsdasdasdas asda sd as asdasda asdasd asda sdasdasd asdasdas...

Comment: @user2197736 What you're asking for isn't possible, see my answer.

Comment: Then what about using Javascript for that?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand how you want this to work.  What is the point of having an ellipsis(...) if you are going to show all of the text anyways?

Comment: This text here is only a sample. I need it for a readmore text. Actually, all I need is just to automatically insert "..." after the end of every text.

Comment: You closed this, but I do have a solution for you to look at anyways.  Here is a **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yw9Dg/1/)** I put together that truncates based on lines.  And [this CSS-Tricks article](http://css-tricks.com/line-clampin/) is where you can find more info.

Comment: Please post it as an answer and I'll see if it can work for me, if it work, I'll mark your answer as the solution. It's opened again.

Comment: Just took a look at your solution, somehow it works, but only based on the text lines. So if I got less than 4 lines? I mean, how can I specify it to insert those "..." after the text, no matter what side it is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow)'s docs on `text-overflow`:

> This property only affects content that is overflowing a block container element in its inline progression direction (not text overflowing at the bottom of a box, for example).

You can't add an ellipsis *bottom* of a box using `text-overflow`.  It only works with inline text.

Comment: No offense, but I couldn't get 35% of what you explained.
What and how should I do then?

Comment: What part didn't you understand?

Comment: "in its inline progression direction"

And a part at the end. Nevermind, I got it now.
So can I solve this if I use Javascript?

Comment: As I got no answer from the other person, his script is good but it's not what I needed, I believe your answer is more appropriated, so I'm marking it as the best one. Thx for the great support.